# How to perform matrix operations similar to multiplication fast?

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication, operation

I have two matrices.

```
A<-matrix(c(1,0,2,3),2,2)
B<-matrix(c(0,1,4,2),2,2)
```

Instead of multiplication (`A%*%B`) and having results like:

```
C[1,1]<-A[1,1]*B[1,1]+ A[1,2]*B[2,1]
C[1,2]<-A[1,1]*B[1,2]+ A[1,2]*B[2,2]
C[2,1]<-A[2,1]*B[1,1]+ A[2,2]*B[2,1]
C[2,2]<-A[2,1]*B[1,2]+ A[2,2]*B[2,2]
```

How can I have a modified version of multiplication and get results like:

```
C[1,1]<-min(A[1,1],B[1,1])+ min(A[1,2],B[2,1])
C[1,2]<-min(A[1,1],B[1,2])+ min(A[1,2],B[2,2])
C[2,1]<-min(A[2,1],B[1,1])+ min(A[2,2],B[2,1])
C[2,2]<-min(A[2,1],B[1,2])+ min(A[2,2],B[2,2])
```

?

I know that I can do it with rotation, but am looking for a faster solution.

```
result <- matrix(nrow= 2, ncol= 2)
for(i in 1:2){
  minMat <-t(apply(B,2,function(x) pmin(x, A[i,])))
  result[i,]<-rowSums(minMat)
}
```

Comment: write it in Rcpp? Can you give the rotation solution you have in mind? Can you give an idea of your problem size/constraints (i.e., why do you need it faster?)

Comment: The matrix size is 4000*4000. The solution that I have in mind is

    result<-matrix(nrow= 2, ncol= 2)
    for(i in 1:2){
        minMat <-t(apply(B,2,function(x) pmin(x, A[i,])))
 result[i,]<-rowSums(minMat)
    }

Comment: You can speed up this solution using a `sapply`: (1) define the function `sum.row <- function(i, A, B){minMat <-t(apply(B,2,function(x) pmin(x, A[i,])));  result[i,]<-rowSums(minMat)}` (2) apply it: `t(sapply(1:nrow(A), sum.row, A, B))`.

Comment: @ThomasGuillerme , why not post as an answer?

Comment: user2079550, it would be useful to mention in your question that the real matrices are 4000x4000 (important information should never be left in the comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A piece of the solution could be to use a function as follow (from one of the comments above):

```
## Defining the function
sum.min.row <- function(i, A, B) {
    minMat <-t(apply(B,2,function(x) pmin(x, A[i,])))
    rowSums(minMat)
}

## Applying it to the whole matrix
t(sapply(1:nrow(A), sum.min.row, A, B))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    1    2
```

This is still not optimal though...

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I tried it. I couldn't find tangible improvement.